# Personal My Site Upload Quota Exceeded Error

Tags: 2007, my-site, quota

User Gets This Error Message:

> Your changes could not be saved
>   because this SharePoint Web site has
>   exceeded the storage quota limit. You
>   must save your work to another
>   location. Contact your administrator
>   to change the quota limits for the Web
>   site.

**My Solution or Attempt:**

Central Administration>Application Management>Site Collection Quotas and Locks>Changed from Default Individual to Personal>then>Quota Templates>Editing an Existing Template checked>limit site storage and email 500mb, it was blank by default.

The user is still getting errors. Did i do it wrong or is there another property that I need to check?

Comment: @Melissa: Can you please ease up on the caps and remember to use appropriate tags for your questions. Thanks and welcome :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, all you did is update the template, not update the quota for the site.  Go to Central Admin->Application Management->Site Collection Quotas and locks

Select the site in question, and then change it to your new quota template, a different quota template, or individual quota.